# SQL count without group by to return zero when no matches

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server. This is part of a stored procedure.

If I have a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(a) AS countA, b
FROM [dbo].[tbl] AS TBL
WHERE TBL.site='100'
  AND TBL.status='status'
  AND TBL.b IN (SELECT b FROM @tbTemp)
GROUP BY TBL.b
```

`@tbTemp` contains a list of ids `1,2,3,4` etc.

I need to return column b with my count, so am forced to use a group by.

This now returns no records when the where condition fails.

How can I return both count(a) and b, and if the WHERE condition fails return a 0?

Thank you

Comment: Why the `GROUP BY` at all? `b` only has a single possible value, so you don't actually need it.

Comment: Can you share sample date you're running these queries on?

Comment: In my opinion, both question and answer as they currently stand don't make any sense. Would be great to see some sample data and expected results here.

Comment: To repeat by comment from the (now deleted) answer, why not just have `1 AS b` in the `SELECT`, or `<Scalar Value> AS <Column Alias>` in Psuedo-SQL terms?

Comment: One moment I will provide more detail in my question. I thought the simplification was enough but understand it's not. Apologies

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: That query massively changes the question. You should be `LEFT JOIN`ing from your table type parameter and grouping on that, not the column in your physical table.

Comment: Firstly, sorry I thought my simplification was enough. Your last comment solved my issue. I needed to select on the not-physical table and then LEFT JOIN the real one. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have upped your answer, but don't know how to mark it as the solution. If I can be told how I will.